# @Ajax.ActionLink generates URL with route parameter instead of POST body, throws jQuery exception on click

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to render a series of buttons in a ASP.NET MVC 5 View.

Each button should invoke an HTTP POST action in the controller, passing a `reportId` parameter as part of the POST body. The reportId is a GUID in the typical `{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}` format.

Here is the view content which renders the buttons:

```
@foreach (Subscription sub in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Ajax.ActionLink(
                sub.Description,
                "SendReport",
                new {reportId = sub.SubscriptionID},
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    Confirm = $"Email {sub.Description} report?",
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    LoadingElementId = "sending-" + sub.SubscriptionID,
                    UpdateTargetId = "submitstatus-" + sub.SubscriptionID
                },
                new { @class = "btn btn-default"})
            <span id="sending-@sub.SubscriptionID" style="display: none">Sending...</span>
            <span id="submitstatus-@sub.SubscriptionID"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

It shouldn't be necessary to specify that the `AjaxOptions.HttpMethod = "POST"` [because the MSDN documentation says that POST is the default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.httpmethod%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but I've included that for clarity.

I have installed the `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive-Ajax` package version 3.2.3.
I've added a bundle to the `App_Start\BundleConfig.cs` for the additional scripts:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryajax").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax*"));
```

And I've added the script bundle to the default `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryajax")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
  </body>
</html>
```

And I've checked that the web.config enables unobtrusive AJAX:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

When I view the page in Internet Explorer 11, the buttons render nicely as buttons, and they do display the confirmation dialog when clicked. I believe this is functionality that the AJAX script provides, which indicates that the script is loaded correctly.

But the button action URL includes the reportId, eg `/Home/SendReport?reportId=%7B86D7B9E1-1D13-4EE8-8059-7F03C17520CD%7D`. I was expecting the reportId to be submitted as POST body content. I was expecting that the action URL would just be the controller action e.g `/Home/SendReport`, without the reportId parameter.

Question 1: Why is the reportId in the button URL and not just the POST body?

Question 2: When the button is clicked, an exception is thrown inside jQuery-3.2.1.js.

```
Unhandled exception at line 1580, column 2 in 
http://localhost:64690/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #sending-{55E625A8-1754-42AE-AD11-C1AEF10EB208}
```

I don't understand what's causing this exception. Is it because of the incorrect URI? Is there something wrong with this id value?

Comment: `new {reportId = sub.SubscriptionID},` adds a query string value to your url (use `Ajax.BeginForm()` with a hidden input if you do not want the value in the url

Comment: Better to use `@Ajax.BeginForm` instead of `@Ajax.ActionLink` to submit input controls with AJAX, and `new {reportId = sub.SubscriptionID}` attempts to add `reportId` parameter value which may cause incorrect URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments I received, I replaced the ActionLinks with BeginForms with a hidden input field to store the corresponding reportId.

I also stripped the { and } characters from the HTML element IDs used by AJAX, which fixed the jQuery exception. I suppose these characters interfered with locating the elements in JavaScript.

```
@foreach (Subscription sub in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
                "SendReport", 
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    Confirm = $"Email {sub.Description} report?",
                    LoadingElementId = "sending-" + sub.SubscriptionID.Trim('{', '}'),
                    UpdateTargetId = "submitstatus-" + sub.SubscriptionID.Trim('{', '}')
                }))
            {
                <input type="hidden" name="reportId" value="@sub.SubscriptionID"/>
                <input type="submit" value="@sub.Description"/>
            }
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="sending-@sub.SubscriptionID.Trim('{', '}')" style="display: none">Sending...</span>
            <span id="submitstatus-@sub.SubscriptionID.Trim('{', '}')"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```